# May sick Jews wait less for meat and dairy

Tags: halacha, meat-and-milk, choleh-sick, yoreh-deah, leniencies

According to Halacha is there any leniency for sick Jews to wait less time between meat and dairy or no? Not in a situation of pikuach nefesh but just of general health and wellness?

Comment: Waiting at all (even eating meat and cheese together without cooking) is only a rabbinic prohibition so even sickness below pikuach nefesh could permit it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Chochmas Adam [40:13](https://www.sefaria.org/Chokhmat_Adam.40.13?lang=bi) says that he can wait an hour and clean their teeth/mouth:

> ומ"מ לצורך חולה קצת נ"ל פשוט דיש להתיר אפילו אכל בשר בהמה לאחר שימתין שעה ויחטט שיניו לאחר בה"מז (שם)

Comment: This is for חולה קצת a minor illness. We might be even more lenient for a major illness.

Comment: So what does this mean? If I have a cold I can just wait one hour now instead of six? What שייכות does meat and milk have with being sick?

Comment: If you need to eat milichig for your health, like hot milk or something

Comment: ... or a pregnant woman having cravings, according to some rabbis...

Comment: @CuriousYid If you have a big headache and need coffee and all that's available in the teacher's lounge is dairy lattes

Comment: Fair enough guys